# Me podrian ayudar con ejercicio de guia en C#

Tags: c#

Dado como datos dos valores enteros P y Q, determine si los mismos satisfacen la siguiente expresión: 3 +4 −22 <680 En caso afirmativo, debe imprimir los valores de P y Q.

No es que quiera que la hagan por mi, pero ya llevo mas de una hora tratando de entender cual podria ser el problema , sera un error de sintaxis o que me falta? no importa que numero ponga nunca me da el resultado de else solo de if

```
{
    int P, Q;
    Console.WriteLine("Escribir si los datos P y Q satisfacen la expresion P^3 +Q^4 −2P^2 <680");
    P = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("El valor de P es:" + P);
    Q = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("El valor de Q es:" + Q);

    if ((P ^ 3 + Q ^ 4) - (2 * P ^ 2) < 680)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Los valores P y Q satisfacen la expresion dada");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No cumplen con los valores ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: ¿P ^ 3 es igual que P elevado al cubo o es realmente el operador ^ (XOR binario)?

Comment: Deberías mirarte la [Clase Math](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.math(v=vs.110).aspx) para saber como realizar operaciones matemáticas complejas en c#.

Comment: En C# no existe un operador para la potenciación. Deberás usar el método `Math.Pow`.

Answer (score 2):

el operador `^` no aplica para calcular el exponente.
existe en c# la función `Math.Pow` que hace ese trabajo

tu condición debería ser de la siguiente manera (no esta probado)

```
if ((Math.Pow(P, 3) + Math.Pow(Q, 4)) - (2 * Math.Pow(P, 2)) < 680)
```

saludos

Comment: Gracias por la informacion me ayudo bastante